# Kibana: Time read wrongly

Tags: csv, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I'm new to Kibana and I use Elasticsearch and Logstash to search & process the data. I have encountered a problem as shown in the image below, I have no idea how to phrase it thus I attached an image below. The time was supposed to be 0:00 but instead it starts with 08:00. Any idea why and how to resolve this?

[image]

Comment: What field are you defining in the index pattern in Kibana for the timestamp (since @timestamp isn't set to the same value and bbwTIme is a string)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, it's the timezone support issue. Kibana 4 doesn't support global timezone. To explain why it appears as  08:00:00.00, it's because that Kibana follow your local browser's timezone, I did an experiment by changing it to other timezone, and yes, it follows the timezone.

Thanks for anyone who tried to help me, much appreciated :)

The ticket raised : https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/1600

Answer (score 0):

Apart from checking what https://stackoverflow.com/users/677561/alain-collins has mentioned, check for the dateFormat:scaled  setting in your kibana's advanced tab. The formats of date mentioned in the setting should match the date format in which elastic search provides it to the dashboard